# Displaying random number in Electron using Python Script

Tags: python, electron

i'm creating a desktop application that make use of Python as the backend application. In a simple scenario i would like to display random numbers continuously (For e.g. in console window)

```
import random
from time import sleep

while True:
   print "Random number: " + str(random.randint(1, 10))
   sleep(0.5)
```

I came upon this article https://www.fyears.org/2017/02/electron-as-gui-of-python-apps-updated.html which make use of the input to calculate the numbers dynamically.

May i ask how do i implement the script above without using any button? I'm stuck with what to put in the renderer.js to render the above logic.

Comment: I think using two languages for such simple purpose is an overkill. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) to generate random numbers in javascript. Still, if you want to have two applications you need to pass the numbers to electron app, which can be done through simple REST interface

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same effect in HTML?? A new line will be appended when there is a new random number generated